# Need to display the data from dataframe list created. I have created a dataframe list from excel data which is separated from blank row

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, apply

I have set of data in multiple rows, present in single column, I have created a dataframe form the excel by separating with blank row,

i have got list like below
"[[                                              SENDER
0                                           NPOEPORT
1                                RECEIVER     : AVB
2                            MESSAGE TYPE : XYZ-01
3                      CONTROL NO.  : 01234
4                  ID           : ABC453
5                    DATE         : 2022/11/21 03:08
6     Segment          Element               ErrorDescription
7     DGS              DGS_02_01_8351         177 data'element too short]]"

now i am trying to get the list where string "data element too short" is present,
from below code i am getting the list separated by blank row,

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(email_list['SENDER'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(numpy.split(df1,df1[df1.isnull().all(1)].index))
df3 = str(df2)[2:-2]
substring = '01234'
mask = df2[df2.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains(substring ).any(), axis=1)].values"""
```

If i find the string which at begining then list populate, but can't find with string "data element too short"

Comment: In the example you provided the substring `data element too short` is written  `data'element too short`, could it be the problem ?

Comment: No, that is mistakenly written while posting, even all the data if i search which are the beigingin of the list then they could be found, but the string i am searching is at the end,